# How to Retrieve data between two dates on vba?

Tags: excel, vba

I currently have a userform which asks the user to input a start and end date. From there i need the user entry to retrieve data  between the two dates from a worksheet named "Job", and paste it in another worksheet named "Summary"

Pls Help me

Answer (score 0):

Easiest approach is to apply an autofilter on the Job sheet, filter the data between the dates specified, copy the visible cells and paste to the Summary sheet. Record a macro doing these actions manually and then adjust it to take input from the userform.